# iOS ADBannerview - do the ads go away on their own?

Tags: ios, objective-c, adbannerview

Do the ads go away on their own? I've read that the ads should be shown for thirty seconds before closing them, implying that their display is managed by the app, but in pre-release testing they disappear after thirty seconds on their own.

Also, if I provide an in-App purchase for an ad-free upgrade, what's the best way to prevent ads from loading? Preventing the ad from *showing* is easy with `.hidden = YES`, but it still loads in the background. If I clear the delegate and dealloc, will that have problems with ARC or threading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the ad from superview, clear the delegate, and set it to nil.

There should be no problems with that. I do it all the time :)

Comment: if using Swift:  adBannerView.removeFromSuperview()
            adBannerView.delegate = nil
            adBannerView = nil

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the banner free version what about setting the property?

`self.canDisplayBannerAds = NO;`